# Can a MacBook's Thunderbolt port be used as an HDMI "in" to view a feed/signal from a video camera?

Tags: thunderbolt, hdmi

I am a filmmaker who wants to be able to use my macbook as an external monitor for a video camera in a studio-interview type setting. The camera is decent, but its screen is small and I don't have any external monitors handy (money is tight). Is there some software that would be able to receive an HDMI-out signal from my camera and then display it on the macbook screen via an HDMI → Thunderbolt adaptor (I have one)?

So the flow would look like this:

Camera → HDMI Cord → HDMI-to-ThBt Adaptor → Software to look at what the camera is sending → my eyes.

Recording the feed is not necessary.

Comment: I very much doubt it. Your "HDMI > Thunderbolt" adapter is most likely a "Thunderbolt > HDMI" adapter… big difference.

Comment: HDMI input to Mac is not cheap, & you're looking at 'proper' video companies to provide it - like BlackMagic - https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/intensity/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not directly.  You can buy any number of HDMI capture hardware that connect via thunderbolt or FireWire and use a thunderbolt FireWire adapter.